# CASE Statement Add Leading Zero 0 SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a case statement which looks like this

```
SELECT
Location,
CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN '05' ELSE '01' END AS id
FROM Locations
```

This however returns 5 or 1 without the leading zero.

I've tried `CAST('05' AS sql_variant)` but I'm going to use this select as an insert statement into a table and its a nvarchar field so it doesnt like that.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: That shouldn't strip the leading zero as both branches are strings.

Comment: How are you running the query? It should be showing `'05'` or `'01'`. Unless this is a subquery unioned to other subquery that has integer column there and these values are converted.

Comment: Nope that is literally the full SELECT no subqueries etc

Comment: What are you doing with the results? Are you inserting them to a table? If so what is the definition of that? Are you viewing them in an application? If so what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your query on SQL 2008R2 and it works fine..

You could always do this:

```
SELECT
 Location,
 right('0'+convert(varchar(2), CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN '5' ELSE '1' END), 2) AS id
FROM Locations
```

Are you binding the value in a variable or are you inserting directly in another table?
    ex:
    INSERT INTO table2 SELECT ...

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat, got no idea why the other statement didnt work

Answer (score 1):

SELECT
Location,
CASE WHEN id BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN convert(nvarchar,'05') ELSE convert(nvarchar,'01') END AS id
FROM Locations

will do